# using JUnit to test a method

Tags: java, junit

I have searched everywhere and I can't find a way to test this type of method on how to write a Junit test on this method

Please

```
 private void AddToTable(String itemName, int itemQuantity){
    DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)itemTable.getModel();
    String expiryDate = ((JTextField)jDateChooser2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String dateAdded = dtf.format(localDate);
    table.addRow(new Object[]{itemName, itemQuantity, dateAdded, "Date", expiryDate});
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this method is a good candidate for unit testing, since the method depends on a number of fields that I assume are defined in the same class, and you're manipulating a Swing UI. In addition, it's a private method, so you can't access it outside of this class (such as in a unit test). Short version: in it's current form it's impossible.

Comment: You can't directly test this method, you have to test it through the methods that use this method.

Comment: You could use something like mockito to assert that certain methods have been called a certain number of times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a private method, you cannot test it directly and probably won't need to.

You could though test it indirectly by testing the method that calls it and checking the `DefaultTableModel` returned by `itemTable.getModel()` since it seems to be a field in your class and assuming you have a getter for it.

You should try to write code that is testable, for example having methods that are package protected, so that you can access them in your test class assuming the latter is in the same package and try to have methods return something, `void` methods are rather difficult to test, you can only test for their impact.